# How do you say "Do not die before I do?"

Tags: expressions

I'm writing a letter in French to my fiancé who is originally from a French speaking country.
We usually communicate in English but I want to impress him by writing "Don't die before I do" in French.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. I want to tell my boyfriend is "I want you live longer than I do.". I'm sorry that I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without more context, I suggest "**Ne meurs pas avant moi.**"(=> literally *don't die before me*) You can't have a word for word translation because translating *I do*  in French would be redundant and sound clumsy at best.

Now, there are many other ways to express the idea of death. Like :

- Partir
- Quitter ce monde/cette Terre
- S'en aller
- Rejoindre les cieux/l'au-delà

And much more.

But since I don't know the general tone of your letter, I can't say if they would be appropriate to use.

**Edit**

Taking your last comment into account, you can use the expression *survivre à quelqu'un* to express the idea of outliving someone.

*I want you to outlive me* can thus translate to *Je veux que tu me survives*. But *Je veux* can sound a bit harsh so I would tone it down a bit and say **Je souhaite que tu me survives** (*Je souhaite* => *I wish*).

Comment: Ne clamse pas avant moi.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps C'est bien pour ça que j'ai arrêté là l'énumération. Il y a plein d'autres façon de le dire : crever, claquer, passer l'arme à gauche, casser sa pipe. Mais je doute que ce soit dans le ton d'une lettre qu'on écrirait à sa/son fiancé(e) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Something you see quite frequently in dramas when someone is dying and their significant other don't want them to die is:

> Ne me laisse pas seul(e) !

(lit. : "don't leave me alone"). However in your context (you writing to your girlfriend) it doesn't work unless she is really dying. For your very context there is no French expression that I know that is as common as "Don't die before I do". You will have to make something up. Anyway all the ways I see to express this idea sound terribly corny, way more than the English expression:

> Ne meurs pas avant moi ! (direct translation)
>
> Attends moi pour mourir ! (sounds a bit better imho)

Answer (score -1):

The exact translation would be: **Ne meurs pas avant que je le fasse.**

Comment: I think "Ne meurs pas avant moi" would be better understood.

Comment: Cela peut marcher mais il nous faudrait plus de détails sur le texte précédant cette phrase, pour être sûrs que *je le fasse* ne puisse pas être comprit comme se référant à une action autre que celle de mourir.